# unittest2 error: TypeError: _recursive_repr() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, odoo, unittest2

I am trying to install openerp, which requires unittest2.  I had to manually install it using pip (and I also tried easy_install) which seemed to work, but anything that touches it (including `unit2`) produces the following traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/unit2", line 7, in <module>
    from unittest2.__main__ import main_
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from unittest2.collector import collector
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/collector.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unittest2.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 13, in <module>
    from unittest2 import case, suite, util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 18, in <module>
    from unittest2 import result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/result.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest2.compatibility import wraps
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/compatibility.py", line 143, in <module>
    class ChainMap(collections.MutableMapping):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/compatibility.py", line 190, in ChainMap
    @collections._recursive_repr()
TypeError: _recursive_repr() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Trying to start the openerp server produces the same error.  There doesn't seem to be any mention of this problem either here or in the googlesphere.

Any ideas?

Comment: By "manually install it using pip" you mean you just did `pip install unittest2`, or you cloned a repo, cd'd into it, and did `pip install .` or similar?

Comment: Anyway, this is very strange. In 3.2+, `collections._recursive_repr` exists (although it's just `reprlib.recursive_repr`, so I don't know why they wouldn't use it with that name?), but in 2.7 it shouldn't. Also, if it does exist, its argument should be optional. Unless something else is monkeypatching `collections`, I can't see why this would happen.

Comment: Any chance you have a file named `collections.py` or a directory named `collections` in your `site-packages` that's shadowing the stdlib module?

Comment: I did both `pip install unittest2` and `easy_install unittest2`, and it seemed to install fine (for what it's worth.)  I ended trying these because `sudo python setup.py install` from the odoo directory kept stopping with the above error, and I wasn't quite sure what else to try.  Obviously the install itself wasn't the problem, but rather the effect this line 190 `@collections._recursive_repr()` was having.  I don't know a whole lot about python or the collections.py lib so I had no idea what was going on here.

Comment: So I just tried merely commenting out the offending line (line 190 of `unittest2/compatibility.py`) and openerp seems to have fully installed and the server is running.  I'll let you know if I run into problems as a consequence of this "fix".

Comment: If I were you, I'd want to know where that `_recursive_repr` in your `collections` library came from. Look at [the current 2.7 source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py); it's not there. If you have some other code that's monkeypatching `collections` to make it act more like the 3.x version, while `unittest2` is also doing weird things with it, they may collide in other ways that are less immediately visible. And I'm not sure unit testing your unit test framework is going to be a fun project…